# How to use form_overrides on ListField(StringField) in flask-admin?

Tags: mongoengine, wtforms, flask-admin

I have a `WebPage` class to store pages scraped from web.

```
class WebPage(Document):
    html = fields.StringField()
    top_image = fields.StringField()
    images = fields.ListField(fields.StringField())
    ... other fields.
```

I Defined a `MyImageField` to display image fields.

```
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.widgets import Input
from flask import render_template


class MyImageInputWidget(Input):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        return render_template(
                "my_image_widget.html",
                field=field,
            )


class MyImageField(StringField):
    widget = MyImageInputWidget()
```

It is very easy to use with `top_image` field:

```
class WebPageModelView(ModelView):
    form_overrides = {
        'top_image': MyImageField,
    }
```

It looks like

[image]

But how to use form_overrides on `images` field ?